# c# method signature: How to create a code with the signature required by the professor

Tags: c#

At school we have the task of creating a method that checks whether a string is a palindrome.  I wrote the code, but I can not use signature methods.  The signature required by the professor is:

```
bool ItsPalindrom(string read);
```

My code:

```
private void buttonPalindrom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string read = textBoxPalindrom.Text.ToLower();
    read = read.Replace(" ", "");
    int i = 0;
    string ReverseArr = "";
    while (i < read.Length)
    {
        ReverseArr = read[i] + ReverseArr;
        i++;
    }
    if (read== ReverseArr)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("je palindrom");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ni palindrom");
    }
}
```

Comment: even if  the answers may help you in your issue your algorithm is not optimized

Comment: Your professor has asked you to write a method named IsPalindrome that receives a string as input and return a boolean where this boolean is arguably true if the input string is a palindrome or false if not. You should start writing this method in your form class and assume that someone from the UI will call this method. Your logic albeit brute will work but notice that you shouldn't concern your method with elements of the user interface. This is the reason of the bool required as output

Answer (score 4):

Why not? define a method with that signature and move your logic there. Call that method in your event handler

```
bool ItsPalindrom(string read)
{
  //your palindrome logic
}

private void buttonPalindrom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ItsPalindrom(textBoxPalindrom.Text.ToLower());  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A method "signature" is its return type and parameters. You can't change the signature of an event handler (like your button click method), but you can have it call *another* method, refactored from your existing code:

```
private bool IsPalindrome(string read)
{
        read = read.Replace(" ", "");
        int i = 0;
        string ReverseArr = "";
        while (i < read.Length)
        {
            ReverseArr = read[i] + ReverseArr;
            i++;
        }
        return read == ReverseArr;
}
```

Then you just call it:

```
private void buttonPalindrom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string read = textBoxPalindrom.Text.ToLower();
    bool palindrome = IsPalindrome(read);
    if (palindrome )
    {
        MessageBox.Show("je palindrom");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ni palindrom");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. You helped me a lot!!